# Unable to use FQDN when using local network (Ubuntu Server 10.04, dd-wrt)

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-10.04, router

Networking newb here... I seem to be having an odd networking issue.

When I am using a PC/laptop/Smart phone on my local network I am unable to access web pages (or email) on my network server using the FQDN.

Here's the set-up:

- Domain name provider that points to the static IP address e.g. example.com points to 222.111.111.001
- Fixed IP router address: e.g. 222.111.111.001
- dd-wrt router: 192.168.1.1 It has port-forwarding to the Ubuntu server which seems to work as it serves pages, etc to non-local ip addresses. Local machines are issued ip address via DHCP in the 192.168.1.100 to 149 range.
- Ubuntu 10.04 server on 192.168.1.150
- Clients include Linux mint machines, Android phone and get addresses such as 192.168.1.104

If I am on a client on the local network ( 192.168.1.104) and I try to navigate to a webpage on example.com/index.htm then the request times out.
The same sort of thing applies to email - If I am connected on the local network (wirelessly) then I cannot access the IMAP and SMTP servers using mail.example.com

The situation is fine if I am using a non-local network (e.g. my Vodafone mobile network). The device will successfully load example.com/index.htm
The situation is also ok if I navigate to 192.168.1.150/index.htm

Any thoughts on how to trouble shoot this one?
It's obviously a little annoying...

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding how DNS lookups work.

The public domain name that your URL is pointing to is a data record that is offered to the public. It doesn't have anything to do with the DNS service available on your local network.

Check your DD-WRT to make sure that you have a DNS server configured. Try using Google's at 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 for testing that.

If you don't have a DNS server configured in your DHCP service, your devices can't resolve FQDNs on the devices that have received IPs from the router.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running something like a `nslookup` to see what your FQDN resolves to from inside your network?

In addition to the DNS issue possibility, you may only have your port-forwarding set up for connections originating outside of your LAN. It could also be many other things, hard to say with limited information.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using DD-WRT. That's unfortunate. I (and others here) have found it to be notoriously unreliable.

Insure that DNS is working. From your local network client (192.168.1.104) do a DNS lookup on your domain `example.com` and make sure the correct 222.111.111.001 address is returned. This will verify that DNS is functioning appropriately for your local clients.

Then see if you can access your server from a local client using its "external" IP address (i.e., 222.111.111.001). If you *cannot* access your server this way, then I suspect your router is the problem. If you *can* access your server, I suspect DNS or possibly a bad virtual hosting configuration (you mentioned a webserver) could be at fault.

- Make sure you are using an "approved" build of DD-WRT. Upgrade (or downgrade) to one of the forum recommended builds listed in this section, especially if you are running SP1 or v24 final (05/21/08 )13064 or 14896. Read this [forum thread](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=51486). Make sure you don't just blindly flash your router with firmware - you'll have to troll through forums to find out which version of DD-WRT works best with your particular router, version and revision.
- Provided your DNS is functioning correctly, this could be caused by a bug in DD-WRT that breaks [NAT Loopback](http://svn.dd-wrt.com:8000/ticket/1868).